# Add object to an array and refresh the sectionList

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I added a new object of contact and trying to show it in SectionList.  But when I trying to put an object to array I'm getting an error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.data.length')

I used the instructions in this link to solve the problem.
[how to add a new object as a value to an array in the react state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558721/how-to-add-a-new-object-as-a-value-to-an-array-in-the-react-state)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);   

    this.state = {
      contacts : [],
      newContactDialogVisible: false,
      contactName : '',
      contactPhone : ''
    }
  }
```

```
refreshContactsList = () => {
    const newContact = {'name': this.state.contactName, 'phone': this.state.contactPhone};
    Alert.alert(newContact.name + " " + newContact.phone); // Alert working and shows the right data
    this.setState({ contacts: [...this.state.contacts, newContact] });
  }
```

```
<SectionList
            sections={this.state.contacts}
            renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>}
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the solution of the link correctly. Missing wrapping brackets.

```
this.setState(state => ({
  contacts: [...state.contacts, newContact]
}));
```

I think you can go shorter with

```
this.setState({ contacts: [...this.state.contacts, newContact] });
```

And I would like to add that

```
this.refreshContactsList = this.refreshContactsList.bind(this);
```

is not necessary since `refreshContactList` is an arrow function and you won't lose `this` pointer inside. If you declare it as `refreshContactList() {...}` you need to bind `this`.

Comment: You are right, I have corrected. But now I'm getting an error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.data.length')

Comment: Can you please log `this.state.contacts` right before `setState`?

Comment: And please remove single quotes (`'`) of property names of `newContact` :)

Comment: I think my problem is with contacts declaration. I did an Alert to this.state.contacts (console.log not working for me) and it restart my app (I'm using expo) .

Comment: Something wrong with putting a newContact inside ```this.setState({ contacts: [...this.state.contacts, newContact] });``` because contacts is array of objects

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the right syntax of how to it:

```
refreshContactsList = () => {
    const newContact = {data: [{name:this.state.contactName, phone:this.state.contactPhone}]};
    this.setState({ contacts: [...this.state.contacts, newContact]})
  }
```

Comment: nice :) so this is kinda expo thing that you need to add `data` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the wrong arrow function syntax. Try this

```
this.setState(state => {
    return {contacts: [...state.contacts, newContact]};
});
```

Comment: When there is a open brace after the => symbol it treats that as body of the function instead of returning it as an object.

Comment: Thank you for response. But now I'm getting an error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.data.length').
I think I don't need to return something, because the setState is making the work